# php file_put_contents writes a string instead instead of boolean

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending an ajax request to my server and using `file_put_contents()` to update a json file value from `true` to `false` or vice versa. The file looks like this:

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "nice_guy": false
}
```

When I write to the file using `file_put_contents()` the `nice_guy` value which is a boolean, has quotes around it like this:

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "nice_guy": "true"
}
```

On the client, if I `console.log` the value before it is sent, I see the unquoted value like this:

```
    {function: "update", nice_guy: true}
Here is the php code:

      if($_POST['nice_guy'] == true || $_POST['nice_guy'] == false){
      $prefs = json_decode(file_get_contents("users/".$_SESSION['email']."/prefs.json"),true);        
$prefs['nice_guy'] = $_POST['nice_guy'];
        file_put_contents("users/".$_SESSION['email']."/prefs.json",json_encode($prefs,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));       
      }
```

Comment: Probably because when you pass `true` via POST (not only POST), values come in as strings. If you need them to be something else, you need to convert them. Since it is a string, and not actually a boolean, json_encode encodes it as a string.

Comment: Print out `$prefs` before you `json_encode` – is `nice_guy` a boolean or a string at this point? `json_encode` will encode what you give it, so if you give it a string, it’ll print a string.

Comment: Just so you know, `true == 'true'` is `true` (same with `1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to store the value as a string instead and then test the string's value to deliver a boolean to the client. So here is what the file looks like now:

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "nice_guy": "true"
}
```

And when I need to send it to the client, I am testing it like this:

```
$prefs = json_decode(file_get_contents("users/".$_SESSION['email']."/prefs.json"),true);
$to_client = $prefs['nice_guy']==="true"?true:false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way. You stringify your json data in JavaScript, then decode it on PHP into a StdClass object. Here is how you could do it

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        //Load JQuery
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='button' value='Send'/>
        <script>
            $('input').on('click', function() {
                $.post('test.php', {json: JSON.stringify({boolean: true })}, function(response) {});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php 
$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);
echo is_bool($json->boolean) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Output:

```
Yes
```